# Interaction.author isn't defined but I already defined "interaction"

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

**Code:**:

```
fs.writeFile("./logs.txt", `Hug command executed by ${interaction.author}`, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }
            console.log("The file has been saved!");
        });
```

**logs.txt:**
[Logs.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNcOP.png)

**Console:**
[Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjmqO.png)

Yes I did define `interaction` when making the slash command "async execute(interaction){
**rest of code**
}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interaction.author` does not exist

Instead you should use `interaction.user`

Your code will look like

```js
fs.writeFile("./logs.txt", `Hug command executed by ${interaction.user}`, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }
            console.log("The file has been saved!");
        });
```

You can also get the tag/username by adding `.tag`, `.username`

Read [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs) to help yourself out

Answer (score 0):

So my IRL friend came online and helped me, he told me instead of going to each command and putting the same code there he told me to go to `index.js` and put this code

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    var member = interaction.user.tag

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }

    fs.appendFile("logs.txt", `${interaction.commandName} command executed by ${member}\n`, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err)
        }
        console.log("The file has been saved!");
    });
});
```